# How to count items inside a list of an object?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object class:

```
public class Country
{
        public string Name { get; }
        public int Land { get; }
        public List<string> Resources { get; }

        public Country(string name, int land, List<string> resources)
        {
            Name = name; 
            Land = land; 
            Resources = resources;
        }    

        public static List<Country> GetCountries()
        {
            return new List<Country>()
            {
                 new Country( "Venezuela", 882050,
                 new List<string> { "petroleum", "natural gas", "iron ore", "gold", "bauxite", "other minerals", "hydropower", "diamonds" }),
                 new Country( "Peru", 127006,
                 new List<string> { "copper", "silver", "gold", "petroleum", "timber", "fish", "iron ore", "coal", "phosphate", "potash", "hydropower", "natural gas"}),
                 new Country( "Paraguay", 397302, 
                 new List<string> { "hydropower", "timber", "iron ore", "manganese", "limestone" })
            };
         }
        public override string ToString() =>
                 $"\n{Name} {Land} \nResources: {string.Join(", ", Resources)};

}
```

In my Main I want to list countries in the descending order, according to the number of the natural resources they have, using LINQ. I am thinking I need to count the Resources inside each of the object and then sort according to the Resources numbers. So far I've got this:

```
List<Country> countries = Country.GetCountries();
ListCountriesResourceDesc(countries);

static void ListCountriesResourceDesc(List<Country> countries) 
            {
                IEnumerable<Country> sortedCountries =
                from country in countries
                orderby country.Resources.Count() descending
                select country;

                Console.WriteLine("Sorted countries according to number of resources:");
                foreach (Country country in sortedCountries)
                    Console.WriteLine(country.Name + " " + country.Resources.Count());
            }
```

But I am getting an error message:

> CS1061: 'Country' does not contain a definition for 'resorceNum' and no accessible extension method 'resourceNum' accepting a first argument of type 'Country' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this:   `orderby resorceNum descending` instead of `orderby country.resorceNum descending`. Reason: `resourceNum` is a variable not a property of class `Country`

Comment: You would need to return a new type instead of `Country` - country doesn't have a count of resources property. You could return an anonymous type with `select new { country, resorceNum }` (I would spell resource correctly or rename to `ResourceCount`)

Comment: You need to be far more careful with your spelling.  `resorceNum` and `resourceNum` are not at all the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LINQ query you need is the following one:

```
from country in countries
orderby country.Resources.Count() descending
select country;
```

As the error message implies there isn't any definition for `resorceNum` on type `Country`. The type `Country` has a list of resources of type `List<String>` and that is what you need to check its size for make the ordering you described.